# Are my computer specs too weak to perform a sub division on a plane with 100 subdivisions?

Tags: texturing, performance, subdivision-surface

I am trying to learn texturing with cycles and I am running into a problem trying to apply a displacement map. The tutorial I am following takes a plane subdivides it 100 times and then applies a sub surface modification set at level 3.

When I try the sub surfacing, the modification is never added to the feature tree. I try putting in 2 or 3 levels and then click apply and nothing happens. I do not see the computer working or anything. When I switch to edit mode i just see a sea of orange and cannot distinguish between the lines. From that point forward I am able to pan and zoom on the plane but I cannot make further edits.

My specs on my computer are, skylake i5, 32gb of ram and nvidia 970 gfx card. I am not trying to render a huge scene just learn how to do textures and some minor illustrations with blender.

Is my computer not powerful enough?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is that tutorial, can you post a link. to me subdivides 100 times and add subsurf sounds crazy to just learn how to do textures.

Comment: @Strapicarus Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk). I wanted to learn make real nice renderings for my figures. I was hoping to use cycles to get very sharp looking textures. The 100 subdivisions and 3 sub layers is the last step at around 5min. Let me know if you know of better starting points for learning cycles and textures.

Comment: That number of subdivisions does not seem like too much for a system like yours (on my laptop I have only 8GB of RAM and I can easily use a displacement modifier on a plane of 100 by 100 vertices with a subsurf level of 3)  How large are the images you want to use for the displacement? and more importantly what other elements are on the scene and what level of detail are you using on it?

Comment: @cegaton I have nothing else in the scene. I started from a new file, where I delete the cube and draw a plane and then start putting the subdivisions in. I am using version 2.78c.

Comment: How many vertices are you dealing with? (in the top of the blender interface you can see the number of vertices/faces/tris on a scene

Comment: Well have to say that subdivide 100 times its not equal to subdivide 100 cuts, i have a very low spec machine and i do it (with lag) without problem, making 100 cuts and adding subsurf level 3 as belnder guru tutorial. my spects, cpu Pentium D @ 3Gh, 4 Gb Ram, nvidia 9400gt 1Gb.

Comment: That sea of orange you see is all the vertices you have created, the fact that you don't notice a delay when applying the modifier means your machine has no problem doing it. If you zoom in close enough you will see each vertex. That method is old, have a look at [this newer tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng) to see how to use cycles newer microdisplacement feature.

Comment: @sambler you are correct. Moreover I did not realize that apply just absorbs the modification but it is still there. My computer would choke as I kept sub dividing thinking it was never completed. Thanks for the referal to microdisplacments!